# To check whether the wifi scan is complete

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'm writing a code for getting the information of all the access points in the range continuously.

Here is my code:

```
       myRunnable = new Runnable() {
       @Override public void run() {
       while(){
       wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
       wifi.startScan(); 
       List<ScanResult>results= wifi.getScanResults();
        try{
          //data Logging
            }  
           } 
         } 
        };

      myThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
      myThread.start();
```

As the scanning and logging of data continuous repeatedly, i want to check whether the scan is complete before logging data. 
Is there any flag or function which checks for wifi.startScan() is complete or not , before logging the data.
Could you please help me out with a code.

Answer (score 5):

> i want to check whether the scan is complete before logging data. Is
>   there any flag or function which checks for wifi.startScan() is
>   complete or not , before logging the data. Could you please help me
>   out with a code.

Yes, there is mechanizm designated for this purpose. To reach your goal you need to implement `BroadcastReceiver` that will listen for `WiFi` scans.

All what you need is to create `BroadcastReceiver` with appropriate `IntentFilter`. So you need this action for filter:

```
WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION
```

This action means that an access point scan has completed, and results are available. And then just create `BroadcastReceiver` (statically or dynamically, it's doesn't matter).

If you don't know how to start, look at this tutorial:

- [Android BroadcastReceiver Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a `BroadcastReceiver` listening for the scan results returned from `WifiManager.startScan()`. `onReceive()` allows you to access the scan results directly. It takes about 1 second for the scan to complete and trigger `onReceive()`...

Comment: From my experience, on some devices it takes 25+ seconds.

Answer (score 1):

To build up on the answers above, I just wanted to add the related code to give an example.

**1. Registering for the event**

```
// don't forget to set permission to manifest
wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
context.registerReceiver(this,new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
//check if WIFI is enabled and whether scanning launched
if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled() || !wifiManager.startScan())
{
  throw new Exception("WIFI is not enabled");
}
```

**2. Receiving the result**

To receive, the object registered (in this case this) needs to extend `BroadcastReceiver` and implement the following method:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        List<ScanResult> result = wifiManager.getScanResults();
 }
```